# Не могу поставить большое разрешение в astralinux через virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Появилась потребность в изменении разрешении на virtualbox c astra linux на борту. C начала пытался подключить `"образ диска дополнительной гостевой ОС"`, а после попытался в ручную `sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-dkms` выдает ошибку. После чего, начал пытаться сделать все в ручную, вводил следующие:

> cvt 3440 1440 60
>
> xrandr --newmod "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50 3440 3696 4064 4688 1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
>
> xrandr --addmode Virtual1 3440x1440_60.00
>
> xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 3440x1440_60.00    //после этой команды появляется черный экран

После этих действий я пытался применить новое разрешение, но в итоге получал черный экран. Хочу узнать как решить мою проблему.

P.S. Стоит у меня все на win10, virtualbox 6.1.16, astralinux 1.6, монитор - Samsung Odyssey G5 C34G55TWWI 34

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «выдает ошибку» — так нужно прочитать текст этой ошибки, проанализировать и устранить причину её возникновения.

Comment: @andreymal да на сколько я знаю, мое разрешение все равно не будет в дефолтных настройках

Comment: Зато его станет возможно добавить. А добавить разрешение без корректно установленных видеодрайверов конечно же не получится

Comment: @andreymal разве virtualbox-guest-dkms включает в себя видео драйвера?

Comment: Если точнее, есть пакет virtualbox-guest-x11 со связанными с xorg штучками (но для его работы конечно нужен virtualbox-guest-dkms)

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с данной проблемой,в моём случаи помогло просто настройки разрешения экрана в самой виртуальной машине Windows. Просто ПКМ/Параметры экрана/выбираем нужное разрешение. Virtual Box сама перенастраивается под нужное разрешение.